# Why does my iPhone app icon have vertical lines?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.4

Created an iOS app with XCode 4.4.1 and the icon for the archived app and what is deployed to my device is distorted. It seems to be rendered wider than the allotted space and it has vertical white lines. This isn't a problem with XCode 4.5, but I can't use that yet.

Has anyone experienced this? How do I fix it?

Comment: http://aaronlbratcher.webs.com/evillaugh.htm

Comment: How did you create the icons, what format & tools did you use? Could be a bug with XCode, but doubt it or others would have seen this.

Comment: I used Gimp to edit an image and saved to PNG. It was originally in color, did a grayscale mode and then exported to PNG. It looks fine in preview and other apps.

Comment: Hmmm I just changed the mode to indexed with the Generate optimum palette option and did another export and that seems to have fixed the issue. Strangest thing I ever saw.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the mode to indexed with the Generate optimum palette option and did another export and that seems to have fixed the issue.